# Use result of query in a second query with IN clause

Tags: mysql

I would like to use the result of one query in another query. This has been asked before, but the answers didn't help me to find a solution.

The first query is like so:

```
    SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed';
```

I can put that in a variable:

```
    set @variable =(SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed');
```

The second query would be like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3,4...);
```

I thought, this could work:

```
    set @variable =(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID) FROM table_1 WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed');
    SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE post_id IN (@variable);
```

But it only uses the first value. Probably, the result is considered a string and not an array of values. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: because @variable is string GROUP_CONCAT(), and you need something like array of values. @variable should be `set @variable =(SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed');`

Comment: I tried that, but it throws an error 1242: "Subquery returns more than 1 row."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group_concat is´ not needed

and use the first Select directly in the select

Like

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM table_2 
WHERE 
  post_id IN (
              SELECT
                ID 
              FROM 
                 table_1 
              WHERE 
                post_status = 'wc-completed'
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `GROUP_CONCAT()`
Use the result of the query as it is in the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE post_id IN (
  SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE post_status = 'wc-completed'
)
```

but consider also `EXISTS` which can perform better:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table_2 t2 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table_1 t1
  WHERE t1.post_status = 'wc-completed' AND t1.ID = t2.post_id
)
```

Comment: @user2516117 is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Comment: I apologize for any mistake. I thought, the first answer was the earliest one. I am very sorry if this was wrong.

Comment: Well, this is wrong. The answer that you accepted was posted after mine and did not add anything new.